Calculate: $ \int_{\Omega}\frac{x^{-\frac{3}{4}}}{4 \sqrt{1-x^{\frac{1}{2}}}} \ d \lambda_2$, where $\Omega$ is an area bounded by: $r = \cos^3 \phi$

Calculate an integral:
$$
\int_{\Omega}\frac{x^{-3/4}}{4\,\sqrt{\rule{0pt}{4.05mm}\,{1 - x^{1/2}}\,}}\,{\rm d}\lambda_{2}\,,
$$
where $\Omega$ is an area bounded by a curve:
$r = \cos^{3}\left(\phi\right)\,,\
\phi \in \left[\,{-\pi/2,\pi/2}\,\right].$
Hint: use the derivative of $\arcsin$.

Could anybody help me understand how to do that ?.
I know that derivative of arcsin is equal to
$1/\sqrt{\,{1-x^{2}}\,}$, but I don't understand the whole concept of such integral since the curve is described only in one dimension and the function under the integral is also expressed only with x. Yet the integral is to be taken over $2$ dimensional space. I don't understand that. Any help would be appreciated.
Edit:
From comments down below, I understand now that those two dimensions of integration are $r$ and $\phi$. But how do I express $x$ in terms of $r$ and $\phi$ so that I could actually integrate ?.

What is $\lambda_2$?

It means that we integrate over $2$ dimensions - probably $x$ and $y$ but there's no $y$ under the integral so I am confused @user326159

@FixFox oh, I thnik you might be right! Thank you. But then, how to express $x$ in terms of $r$ and $phi$?

For this you would only have to use $x=r\cdot\cos(\phi)$ if it is an integration over polar coordinates. But what confused me, which is why I deleted the comment, is whether you still have to take the derterminant of the Jacobian matrix into account or not. I don't know in which form $\lambda_2$ is expressed.

In Cartesian, $\Omega={(x,y)\mid0\le x\le1\land|y|\le\sqrt{x^{3/2}-x^2}}$, but if $d\lambda_2=dy,dx$, the value of the integral becomes non-real,$$\int_\Omega\frac{x^{-3/4}}{4\sqrt{1-x^{-1/2}}},d\lambda_2\stackrel?=\int_0^1\frac{x^{1/4}\sqrt{x^{-1/2}-1}}{2\sqrt{1-x^{-1/2}}},dx=\frac{2i}5$$

@user170231 I made a mistake. There shouldn't be minus in the power of x in the denominator. I'm so sorry, I've already edited the original question. Maybe now it's easier to calculate that.

In that case, the double integral would reduce to$$\int_0^1\frac{x^{1/4}\sqrt{x^{-1/2}-1}}{2\sqrt{1-x^{1/2}}},dx$$which is easily computed by substitution. But the hint suggesting to recall the derivative of $\arcsin$ makes me wonder if $d\lambda_2$ means something else.

Ok, now it's easier. The problem was that I have misinterpreted the question. I'm sorry. Can you calculate the integral in an answer to that question? That way I can select that as the correct one and close the question + bounty. @user170231

I don't see the point of the hint (or of having the factor of $1/4$). Note that the equation of the boundary curve is $r^4=(r\cos\phi)^3$, so the cartesian equation is $(x^2+y^2)^2=x^3$. (It is reassuring that we have $|\phi|\le\pi/2$, so $x\ge 0$.) Thus, the cartesian equation of the boundary curve is $y=\pm\sqrt{x^{3/2}-x^2}=\pm x^{3/4}\sqrt{1-x^{1/2}}$. Finally, by symmetry, the integral becomes
$$\frac12\int_0^1\int_0^{x^{3/4}\sqrt{1-x^{1/2}}}\frac{x^{-3/4}}{\sqrt{1-x^{1/2}}}dy\,dx = \frac12\int_0^1 1\, dx = \frac12.$$
